Random spwaning TargetLine in a Square
enter image description hereI want a TargetLine in a square to appear at a new position in a square every time I start it.
I am failing with the code...
With the help of ChatGPT I was able to write a code but I still get error messages when executing it
at _1_try.Main.spawnTargetLineRandomly(Main.java:246)
TargetLine is in the main.
extra function spwanTargetLineRandomly is there, filled with ChatGPT Code
no porblems are shown but doesnt execute, just with the given error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Nice username :) . Pls add more details to the question so we can help. What code did you write, what error do you get. Best add screenshots, they often help as well. PS: ChatGPT cannot know AnyLogic very well as there just is not much to learn about it from public sources... So you will always struggle if you don't start learning to use the AL help and API
